# Error Native linking error: framework not found IOSurface for architecture arm64

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am getting the following errors when trying to do a build for my Xamarin.IOS project.

***Native linking error: framework not found IOSurface for architecture arm64.***

***Native linking failed. Please review the build log.***

I am trying to use the UGROKIT xamarin sdk with no luck.  It works fine on my Android project.

I am using VS2015 on windows and the xcode version on the mac is 8.2.1.

I have tried doing a native Reference but that don't seem to work either.

Not sure what else I can do.  Any ideas?

Comment: No, my iPad is still 9.3.5 and the simulators are 10.2.

Answer (score 2):

> Native linking error: framework not found IOSurface for architecture arm64.
>   xcode version is 8.2.1.
>   my iPad is still 9.3.5 and the simulators are 10.2.

`IOSurface` used to be a **private** framework and thus not allowed to be used in apps submitted to the App Store.

In iOS 11 `IOSurface.framework` was changed and it now a public framework, you would have to use Xcode9(+) and target iOS11(+).

re: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iosurface

```
iOS 11
The following new frameworks were added in iOS 11:

ARKit.framework (Augmented Reality)
CoreML.framework (Machine Learning)
CoreNFC.framework (Near Field Communication)
DeviceCheck.framework
FileProvider.framework
FileProviderUI.framework
IdentityLookup.framework
IOSurface.framework
PDFKit.framework (new in iOS, exists in macOS)
Vision.framework
```

re: [Xamarin.iOS 11.0/#Whats_New](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/ios/xamarin.ios_11/xamarin.ios_11.0/#Whats_New)

Answer (score 0):

after I added this line to my project, I get the same error

```
using FFImageLoading;
```

`ImageService.Instance.LoadFile(ViewModel.BannerUrl).Into(ImageBunner);`

when I removed that, my project Build successfully!

I don't know why !!!