# Error iOS project :-native linking error:framework not found IOSurface for archtecture arm64

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Getting Error while building iOS project as :

> Native Linking Error: framework not found IOSurface for architecture arm64
>    2.Native Linking failed. Please review the build log.

I'm building the Xamarin.Forms application on a Windows PC by connecting it to Mac.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47764718/error-native-linking-error-framework-not-found-iosurface-for-architecture-arm64 may help

Comment: @brandon Yes pls

Comment: Have you solved the issue by installing xcode 9?